# How to force login to oauth with specific email address?

Tags: oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Lets say I want a specific user to login with a specific email address.

dave.myservice.com --> dave@example.com

So, if you accessing this page "dave.myservice.com" , I want my application to make him log in with dave@example.com, not with his other personal accounts.

Is this scenario possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For Google OAuth, you can use the `login_hint` parameter to specify an email you would like the user to login with (cf https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient)